# How to bind observable collections to view number of items present in observable collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, observablecollection

Hi everyone i am working on a project which is configuring a networking device via telnet,i am using C# Wpf. The problem is i have a Observable Collection and i want to display number of items present in the observable collection but it is not displaying . I have tried following :

```
 public ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass> vlan { get; set; }

  public int Vlans
        {
            // Retreive value from Configuration Library
            get
            {
                return this.vlan.Count;

            }
        }
```

XAML is :

```
 <TextBlock Margin="3,0"  
        Style="{StaticResource SummaryValues}"  
        Text="{Binding Path=Vlans}"
        Visibility="Visible"
        />
```

Now it is not displaying anything .Any help would be highly appreciable :)

Comment: Is vlan created before that Vlans get is called?  Have you debugged and seen that line called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest is to simply bind to vlan.Count (in my example i used textbox, but textBlock won't need OneWay).  No extra property or INotifyPropertyChanged needed.  Adding to the collection will update the count automatically.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding vlan.Count, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

or

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding vlan.Count}" />
```

Comment: But why use a TextBox? Better use a TextBlock. Then there is also no need to specify `Mode=OneWay`.

Comment: use whatever control you want, the point is just bind to the collection's count.  this was just an example

Comment: The textblock is not displaying anything ,it is displaying number of counts in back end console but not displaying in my view.

Answer (score 1):

The binding does not know when to update the target.  You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, subscribe to .CollectionChanged and raise a PropertyChanged event when Vlans (the count) changes.

Comment: Yes i know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ListCollectionView on top of the ObservableCollection.

In your ViewModel, define them as:

```
    ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass> vlan;
    public System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView CountingView { get; private set; }
```

Then, initialize the collection to the ObservableCollection:

```
CountingView = new System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView(vlan);
```

In your xaml, bind to the Count property of the collection:

```
<TextBlock Margin="5" Height="35" Width="50" Text="{Binding CountingView.Count}" />
```

I hope this helps!